# Before + gerund

Tags: gerunds

Do I have to say:
`but before finish and publishing by book` or `but before finishing and publishing my book`? Does gerund have to apply on both verbs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep, you need both. As a *general guideline only*, you can work out matters of grammatical agreement involving conjunctions by trying the sentence out with each of the conjoined parts separately:

> but before publishing my book

is ok, but

> but before finish my book

is not. Once you fix it up to "before finishing my book", you can recombine these to get a grammatical sentence.

Alternatively, you could change the parts to "before I finish my book" and "before I publish my book", giving you "before I finish and publish my book". Some people prefer this form, because they feel this makes it clearer that it is *you*, and not someone else, who is finishing and publishing your book.

But that's just a matter of taste :)